# Scrapy crawl list bypass with for loop or str formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm looking for a solution, that my code crawls every item just once.
Since i added the last loop, i receive every item three times.
How can i execute my last loop only once or is it possible to determine all the doubled crawls?

```py
import scrapy
from ..items import TopartItem

class LinkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "link"
    allow_domains = ['topart-online.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.topart-online.com/de/Blattzweige-Blatt-und-Bluetenzweige/l-KAT282?seg=1']
    custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ['title','links','ItemSKU','ItemEAN','Delivery_Status', 'Attribute', 'Values'] } 
    def parse(self, response):
        card = response.xpath('//a[@class="clearfix productlink"]')
        
        for a in card:
            items = TopartItem()
            link = a.xpath('@href')
            items['title'] = a.xpath('.//div[@class="sn_p01_desc h4 col-12 pl-0 pl-sm-3 pull-left"]/text()').get().strip()
            items['links'] = link.get()
            items['ItemSKU'] = a.xpath('.//span[@class="sn_p01_pno"]/text()').get().strip()
            items['Delivery_Status'] = a.xpath('.//div[@class="availabilitydeliverytime"]/text()').get().strip().replace('/','')
            yield response.follow(url=link.get(),callback=self.parse_item, meta={'items':items})

        last_pagination_link = response.xpath('//a[@class="page-link"]/@href')[-1].get()
        last_page_number = int(last_pagination_link.split('=')[-1])
        for i in range(2,last_page_number+1):
            url = f'https://www.topart-online.com/de/Blattzweige-Blatt-und-Bluetenzweige/l-KAT282?seg={i}'
            yield response.follow(url=url, callback=self.parse)
    

    def parse_item(self,response):
        table = response.xpath('//div[@class="productcustomattrdesc word-break col-6"]')

        for a in table:
            items = TopartItem()
            items = response.meta['items']
            items['ItemEAN'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="productean"]/text()').get().strip()
            items['Attribute'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="productcustomattrdesc word-break col-6"]/text()').getall()
            items['Values'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-6"]/text()').getall()
            yield items
```

i only expect 51 elements, but i received 153.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you're getting 3 of every single item is that you're doing a for loop around the table which isn't I think necessary. Although happy to be wrong if the data doesn't make sense.

### Addition

A small addition to the code at the top. I had this put in because to specify how the columns should be come out when you create a CSV FIle. Often with item's you dont get the order of the columns the way you want. Here we have specified them by making scrapy include these settings. We have to to add `attribute` and `value` to that list to include it when you create the CSV document.

```
custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ['title','links','ItemSKU','ItemEAN','Delivery_Status','Attribute','Values'] }
```

### Corrections to code

```
def parse_item(self,response):
    items = response.meta['items']
    items['ItemEAN'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="productean"]/text()').get().strip()
    items['Attribute'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="productcustomattrdesc word-break col-6"]/text()').getall()
    items['Values'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-6"]/text()').getall()
    yield items
```

### Explanation

1. No need to instantiate TopArtItem() in `parse_item` as it's already been instantiated in the `parse` function.
2. No need to use a for loop, just grab the details using response.

### Tips

1. If you did need to do a for loop around a table or any XPATH selector that gives you a list, remember your xpath selectors should be `a.xpath('.//div etc....)` NOT `response('//)`. This is because you want to use `a` instead of `response` or `table`, AND you must use `.//` as you want the relative XPATH NOT `//` which searches the whole document.

By relative path I mean that you are wanting tell scrapy, that you are assuming the xpath selector in `table` is a given in the `.//` XPATH selector and that using the `.//XPATH_SELECTOR`, you are telling scrapy to add that table XPATH selector to whatever is in `.//` XPATH selector. It's a concise way of not having to have a very large string XPATH selector. But it's essential to use if you're doing a for loop around an XPATH selector which has created a list of selectors.

For example

Not code to include but as an example of how to use a for loop when the table XPATH selector gives you a list.

```
table = response.xpath('//div[@class="productcustomattrdesc word-break col-6"]')

for a in table:
    items = response.meta['items']
    items['ItemEAN'] = a.xpath('.//div[@class="productean"]/text()').get().strip()
    items['Attribute'] = a.xpath('.//div[@class="productcustomattrdesc word-break col-6"]/text()').getall()
    items['Values'] = a.xpath('.//div[@class="col-6"]/text()').getall()
    yield items
```

We have used `a` instead of `table` or `response` and we have specifically used `.//` NOT `//`

### Update Per Comments

So for this next question it requires abit of string and list manipulation.

### Change to code

In order for the code to work down below you need to change the `custom_settings`

```
custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ['title','links','ItemSKU','ItemEAN','Delivery_Status','Values'] }
```

You also need to delete in items.py

```
Attributes = scrapy.Field()
```

### Updated parse_items code

```
def parse_item(self,response):
        items = response.meta['items']
        attribute = response.xpath('//div[@class="productcustomattrdesc word-break col-6"]/text()').getall()
        values = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-6"]/text()').getall()
        combined = []
        for i,j in zip(attribute,values):
            combined.append(i.strip().replace('.','').replace(':',': ') + j.strip().replace('\'',''))                 
        items['ItemEAN'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="productean"]/text()').get().strip()            
        items['values'] = ', '.join(combined)
        yield items
```

### Explanation

We define variables `attributes` and `values`. We don't add these to the items dictionary as we want to do some manipulation first.

The combined variable is long but can be easily followed.

We have two lists, `attributes` and `values`, we wnat to combine each respective items from both lists together. The first item from attributes with the first item from values. This can be done by the zip function.

Take an abstract example to understand what zip is doing.

If we have a list called `num = ['1','2','3']` and `letter = [a,b,c]`. `zip(num,letter)`  will create `[('1',a),('2',b),('3',c)]`. Zip creates tuples of each respective list item and puts them in a list.

Now we want to combine all the items of this list into a string as the goal.

We can loop around each list item of `zip(num,letter)` like this

```
combined = []
for i,j zip(num,letter): 
   combined.append(i + j)
```

Which will create `combined = ['1 + a','2 + b','3 + c']`

We then use the `''.join(combined)`, which is a standard way to convert a list into a string to combine all of this into a string.

So we are doing this with this bit of code, except i'm using the strip() method and replacing some letters for each i or j just to tidy it up.

Comment: i thought i have to use response.xpath because its from the whole html of certain item? otherquestion: what does the a stands for in the loop? isnt the correct way to replace "a" through "div"?

Comment: response.xpath('// ... ') searches the WHOLE html not of a certain item. But that's not what you need. 
Your code has for a in table. Now the table variable is a list. So every loop iteration of that list is one item, and every item gets called a. If you want to select HTML tags downstream from the div in the table variable. You need to use .// NOT // as this will search the relative path of table and not the whole document.

Comment: then i missunderstood the construction of html-page. for example: if i have product xy.html and i want to figure out, whats inside that specific page, do i use .// or // because its the whole html page of the item and not as a card like in my example before

Comment: Also tell me if the output doesn't seem right or is not what you desire. I'm not too clear on what you're after specifically. This is the most important aspect of asking about web scraping.

Comment: I think you're not really understanding the difference between // and .//. // should be used if you're after either a very specific piece of data on a page. Or you're after a list of selectors. Your card variable in parse is a good example. You're after 20 blocks of HTML we call cards. But actually the data you want is within each card. So it makes sense to do a for loop around each card item. In that case you need to use .// because you're not wanting to search the whole document. You actually want to search within that specific card items HTML block.

Comment: lets have a look at the for a in table loop: searching for the productean is used by response.xpath('//) because that information is only given on the whole html site of each specific item, that is what i wanted to point out in my question above because the values im looking for in Attribute and Values are also only contained on the html of an product and not findable in a card on the productlink clearfix tag

Comment: Can I confirm that the code gets you the desired result ? Because there's not much point trying to re-explain the difference in // and .// if it's not what you want from the code.

Comment: I must say though, some of this is learning abit more about string manipulation things you should brush up on if you want to deal with data, I feel like I've explained a lot today to you, which is not often the best way to learn. Learning to struggle and figure things out yourself, googling and searching stackoverflow for things you are trying to accomplish rather than asking for results to be handed to you is better for you. Can I ask that if you do ask more SO questions, i must urge you to show an attempt and show us what you've tried, you need to do more work than what you have been.

Comment: It also wouldn't hurt for you to read up on the difference between // and './/' either there are plenty of Stack overflow questions on this and other resources to gain this knowlege.

Comment: i understand the difference between // and .// you explained it very accurate to me. i assume that we were both talking about different things, maybe my question wasnt formulated very well, because im not a native. i started fresh in the company as a trainee but my chef expects in some way things i never touched before, thats why im asking plenty of questions. i have less time for things to accomplish

Comment: I realise that, but if you want to retain this knowledge and take forward the understanding you gain then you need active recall. This requires a journey from you. I expect atleast a 10-15 minute search for things you need to be able to do with python but can't. Verbalising your problem and using google can get you a long way. If you're taking more than 30mins to an hour to find something by all means ask. But again an attempt and what things you have tried from othe resources goes a long way to getting a favourable response.

Comment: i already have an other project writing a crawler where i try to do all bymyself with the information i got from you, so there is a journey of understanding/learning. my plan was to get one finish very quickly so i can do another one just step by step with the things i learned that week

Comment: That's a good thing to do and encourage to do these things yourself, but following my code gives you a superficial understanding, doing it by yourself on a different project gives you a deeper understanding. Following anyones code, or a tutorial is not truely understanding what you're doing.

Comment: my boss is a huge fan of learning by doing, thats the best way imho but i also can be very hard and frustrating. All in all im very very grateful for all of your response, you helped a young lad very very well

Comment: Ha! Yeah your boss is right unfortunately! I think there's a balance though, you need theory and practice, but you will probably learn more if you let practice drive the theory you need to know. A tip is just say in english what you want the program to do, and start skeletoning out the python you do know that may work towards that goal. Then use google/SO when you have an idea of what you need to find out, use that to drive the things you don't know and can find out. Coding is as much coding as is figuring out things you don't know as writing code.